# Clone Windows Server 2019 Standard- Unlicensed to Datacenter/Standard Licensed

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 evaluation OS and its evaluation period has expired, I have perform multiple activation attempts(with license code and kms server) but they both failed.

It has expired more than 2months now it shutdown by itself several times. I used cscript and ipk to install keys but it failed also. The machine is VM.

I need to clone it configurations and restore it to Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. How can I attain this.

Comment: Can you tell us the error that Windows shows you when you try activating your license?

Answer (score 0):

- Block/disconnect towards/from internet
- Re-enter a general use product key from command line (enter a datacenter default key using slmgr.vbs /ipk) - this will make the OS the desired version
- Restart the system
- Enter the licensed key (must be same type/version as the general key you used) - you can enter this one normally or from command line
- Activate your copy of Windows

Comment: this threw an error (0xc004f069 activation error) after disconnecting from network and supply the key with /ipk. I checked the error and it drive me to DISM which was also not validating the key. 
I follow this link [link]https://doitfixit.com/blog/2019/10/09/error-1168-the-specified-product-key-could-not-be-validated/[/link] and later on the MAK worked and system is activated.

Comment: Set-Edition should have happened automatically when applying a default key, but it's a good safety measure if that didn't work directly.